# Selenium Webdriver Stale Element Exception error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Hi I am working with the selenium webdriver and while running the below script, i am facing stale element exception error at the place which i highlighted in the script.

My script stops over there and i can't able to run.

The error message is - Stale Element exception error. The element is not found in the cache perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up.

Anyone please help me in this case and guide me to rectify this error.

Regards,
Vignesh K S

```
@Test
  public void testClient() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://t1accounts.govreports.com.au/?service=govreports");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Viki2607");
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("vignesh@eimpact.com.au");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='side-menu']/li[2]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.hide380")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual")).click();
    //driver.wait(5);
    **driver.findElement(By.id("ABN")).clear();**
    driver.findElement(By.id("ABN")).sendKeys("38091241128");
    driver.findElement(By.id("TFN")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("TFN")).sendKeys("100000001");
    driver.findElement(By.id("BusinessName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("BusinessName")).sendKeys("LORGE CONSULTING (AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD");
    driver.findElement(By.id("TradingName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("TradingName")).sendKeys("LORGE CONSULTING (AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD");
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='Individual_Salutation_listbox']/li")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Salutation")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Salutation")).sendKeys("Ms");
    //new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Salutation"))).selectByVisibleText("Mr");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Salutation")).sendKeys("Mr");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_FirstName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_FirstName")).sendKeys("Joan");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_LastName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_LastName")).sendKeys("Ignatius");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Phone")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Phone")).sendKeys("042323155");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Individual_Email")).sendKeys("test@govreports.com.au");
    driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_Line1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_Line1")).sendKeys("Walker Street");
    driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_City")).sendKeys("SYDNEY");
    driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_Region")).sendKeys("NSW");
    driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_Postcode")).sendKeys("1001");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_Country")).sendKeys("Australia");
    //Select objSelect = new Select(null);
    //new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("PostalAddress_City"))).selectByVisibleText("SYDNEY, NSW, Australia, 1001");
    driver.findElement(By.id("saveClient")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
```

Comment: On which line you are getting exception?

Comment: Why are you even sending data like this? This is hardcoding, you should maintain your testdata in a separate repository as such(excel,database), your testdata should be dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 1):

Just works fine, you may want to add an implicit wait of say 3-5 secs since the application is quite slow.
Alternately, at the element `.//*[@id='side-menu']/li[2]/a/span` you may also do a

```
driver.navigate().to("http://t1hub.govreports.com.au/App/#/Clients/MyClients");
```

I believe the place where you are getting the problem is `ABN`. However it works good if appropriate wait is induced.

Comment: Hi.. Thank you so much.. Its working for me.. I have rectified the stale exception error.. But i am facing one more issue where i can't able to select the drop down values.. In the above script there is a address fields.. These fields are not auto complete fields.. It must i need to select those values from the drop down alone.. I can't know how to access the drop down values.. Please help me..

Comment: That's a different question... please accept this answer if it answered this question and start another one for your new question.

Answer (score 0):

When a Stale Element Exception occurs!!

Stale element exception can happen when the libraries supporting those textboxes/ buttons/ links has changed which means the elements are same but the reference has now changed in the website without affecting the locators. Thus the reference which we stored in our cache including the library reference has now become old or stale because the page has been refreshed with updated libraries.

```
for(int j=0; j<5;j++)
try {
    WebElement elementName=driver.findElement(By.id(“Individual_Salutation”));
    break;
} catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
e.toString();
System.out.println(“Stale element error, trying ::  ” + e.getMessage());
}
```